# Unsubscribe from a BU level, not enteprise level

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, subscriber

How can I make this work?

```
SET @subscriber = CreateObject('Subscriber')
SetObjectProperty(@subscriber,'EmailAddress', EMAIL_ADDRESS)
SetObjectProperty(@subscriber,'SubscriberKey', EMAIL_ADDRESS)
SetObjectProperty(@subscriber, "Status", 'Unsubscribed')


SET @list = CreateObject("SubscriberList")
SetObjectProperty(@list,"ID", LID)
SetObjectProperty(@list, "Client", @client)
AddObjectArrayItem(@subscriber,"Lists", @list)

SET @client = CreateObject("ClientID")
SetObjectProperty(@client, "ID", MID)
SetObjectProperty(@client, "IDSpecified", "true")
SetObjectProperty(@subscriber, "Client", @client)


InvokeCreate(@subscriber, @create_sub_status, @create_sub_errorcode)
```

The result is that I cannot Activate the email on BU, only on parent level. Is this possible?

Thanks

**Update:** Found the solution after a lot of testing

```
/* create subscriber */
SET @subscriber = CreateObject('Subscriber')
SetObjectProperty(@subscriber,'EmailAddress',@EMAIL_ADDRESS)
SetObjectProperty(@subscriber,'SubscriberKey', @EMAIL_ADDRESS)

SET @client = CreateObject("ClientID")
SetObjectProperty(@client, "ID", @MID)

SET @list = CreateObject("SubscriberList")
SetObjectProperty(@list, "ID", @LID)
SetObjectProperty(@list, "Client", @client)
SetObjectProperty(@list, "Status", 'Unsubscribed')

SetObjectProperty(@subscriber, "Client", @client)
AddObjectArrayItem(@subscriber,"Lists", @list)

InvokeCreate(@subscriber, @create_sub_status, @create_sub_errorcode, @CreateOptions)

/* make the record active in global list */
SetObjectProperty(@subscriber, "Status", 'Active')
SET @client = CreateObject("ClientID")
SetObjectProperty(@client, "ID", @MID)

SetObjectProperty(@subscriber, "Client", @client)
AddObjectArrayItem(@subscriber,"Lists", @list)

InvokeUpdate(@subscriber, @create_sub_status, @create_sub_errorcode, @UpdateOptions)
```

Comment: Tell us about the value of the MID... is it the parent level MID, or the child (BU) MID?

Comment: MID is child BU

Comment: Could you host the cloudpage on the Business Unit level and then try it?

Comment: @BradSapkota The page has multiple checkboxes (for each child BU), I don't think this is an option for me. Thanks

Comment: @gibex Are you trying to unsubscribe through one preference page for all BU's?

Comment: @BradSapkota yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue could be occurring for the following reasons:

1. You have the Business Unit Unsubscribe Settings set to "Subscribers will be unsubscribed from all business units in the Enterprise"
2. Your MID is the Parent BU MID

You can try using [Subscriber.Unsubscribe](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_subscriberUnsubscribe.htm) SSJS Function to perform the same operation and see what happens there.

Comment: Actually the "Subscribers will be unsubscribed from all business units in the Enterprise" is set and read-only in parent.